# Working with git submodule and versioned packages at the same time in Python

Tags: python, git, git-submodules, development-environment, python-packaging

#### Is there a way to work with private versioned packaged for deployment/dev purposes and at the same time have the flexibility to use git submodules for dev when needed?

### Context

We have some common Python codes we use across repos (ex. models). Currently, we are consuming these common codes with [git submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules), so in our end repos we can treat our common codes as local. But this approach have caused us some sort of issues, and we want to move to some way of private versioned packages.

### Our ideal world

- Default behavior (deploys/dev): Most of the time we do not change the common codes, like `models`. So, we just want to used as versioned packages and put them in the `requirements.txt` file like any other package.
- Custom behavior (dev only): Some times we have implement new features that require changes in our common codes. With a versioned package workflow, we will have to go to the common code, commit the changes, create a new version, then go the the end repo, use the new version, and test that the common code have everything we need; if something is missing, repeat the process again. However, with git submodule, we could work with both repos (common code and end repo) at the same time. Once finished, we commit the changes to the common code repo, create a new version and start using the default behavior.

### So, Question

Is there a way to achieve our ideal world? I mean work with private versioned packaged for deployment/dev purposes and at the same time have the flexibility to use git submodules for dev when needed.

I'd appreciate if you could share any experience with this or something similar. If this isn't clear enough I could add more details.

Thanks

Comment: IMO you don't need to fix packages or submodules — you should fix testing. Testing should not require releasing a new version of a package. Commit, push to CI, watch test run.

Comment: hey @phd could you expand a little bit more on your comment? I'm very interested. Thanks.

Comment: Workflow: a developer changes something in the common code, commits and pushes. Then it goes to the superproject, creates a new short-lived test branch, commits changes in the submodule and pushes the new branch to your CI. CI runs your tests. If everything is ok one of the developers merges the new branch to the mainline and removes the branch. If tests fail work continues in the test branch until all tests are passed. When the test branch with the submodule merged into the mainline — only after that you create a new version of the common package.